# How to remove inspection for Flex properties files in IntelliJ - "Cannot Resolve Property key"

Tags: apache-flex, properties, intellij-idea, resources

like some people i've trouble with IntelliJ, i can't remove inspections for resources ... i 've got everywhere in my project "Cannot resolve property key" . Actually it's quite normal, because i'm loeading resources from database. So i'm looking for the inspection to remove in IntelliJ settings but can't find it.

i've already unchecked :

```
-> Properties Files
------>Inconsustent Resource Bundle
------>Invalid property key
```

Strange thing : inspections are blue in the settings ... don't know why ...

Anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70100
this is still an open issue in idea.